# How can I get the Tag value from a XAML UI Control without knowing the precise Control type beforehand?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3

I need to get the Tag value of a default XAML control without knowing it's precise type.
I have tried casting to UIElement, which although works for most standard properties, doesn't seem to work for the Tag property.

```
if (control is UIElement e)
{
    object tagValue = e.Tag; //Error: UIElement doesn't contain a definition for Tag
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the control to `FrameworkElement` instead:

```
    if (control is FrameworkElement e)
    {
        object tagValue = e.Tag;
    }
```